# Poisson process. Compute $E[N_z-N_t | N_s=3]$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let $(N_t)_{t  \in[0,\infty)}$ be a Poisson process. Let $t<s<z$. Compute

$E[N_z-N_t | N_s=3]$

My idea:
Using the fact that Poisson process has independent increments:

$E[N_z-N_t| N_s=3]=E[N_z-N_s+N_s-N_t | N_s=3]= E[N_z-N_s]+ E[N_s-N_t | N_s=3]$

Comment: That looks sensible to me.  In the final step, you have implicitly used $E[N_z-N_s \mid N_s=3]=E[N_z-N_s]$, which is true thanks to memorylessness of the Poisson process; you could also say it is $E[N_{z-s}]$ if the rate is constant

Answer (score 1):

As Henry pointed out $E[N_z-N_s] = E[N_{z-s}] = \lambda (z-s)$ (assuming $\lambda$ is the intensity). Also $E[N_s-N_t | N_s=3] = \frac{3(s-t)}{s}$ (since given $N_s=3$ the arrival times are uniformly distributed in $[0,s]$).

Comment: OK. I'm having difficulties understanding why the conditional term gives a Binomial distribution. I understand why the Binomial distribution should have 3 successes, but why is $p=(s-t)/s$

Comment: Given that $N_s=3$, the 3 arrivals are distributed independently and uniformly in the interval $[0,s]$. What is the probability that a uniform$[0,s]$ distribution takes value in $[t,s]$? It is $\frac{s-t}{s}$. Finally, you have three of them. Can you see it now?

Comment: Yes !! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the idea.

$\begin{align}\mathsf E[N_z-N_t\mid N_s=3]&=\mathsf E[N_z-N_s+N_s-N_t \mid N_s=3]\\[1ex]&=\mathsf  E[N_z-N_s\mid N_s=3]+\mathsf  E[N_s-N_t \mid N_s=3]\\[1ex]&=\mathsf  E[N_z-N_s]+\mathsf  E[N_s-N_t \mid N_s=3]\\[1ex]&=\mathsf  E[N_{z-s}]+\mathsf  E[N_s-N_t \mid N_s=3]\end{align}$

Now you need to determine what is the conditional distributions of $N_s-N_t$ given $N_s=3$.

> Binomial(3,(s-t)/s)